# Unable to open Chat Bubble in test chat for Amazon Connect

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-connect

I claimed a number and choose a flow for the number. I am able to call the number and get the correct response from flow. However, I am unable to open Chat Bubble in test chat in the url of instance. When I tried to open the chat, the chat window is pinning and it throws the error "Unable to start the chat, An internal error has occurred." as the image shows.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you AWS team for fixing this issue. Now the error message is gone. Instead, it shows that I didn't fill the "Test Setting". After I filled it, I can successfully use the Chat Bubble.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the Routing profile? Make sure the chat option is checked for the routing profile the agent is assigned to.

[Select chat in routing profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mff7F.png)

Other things to make sure. Where you have added the script for chat widget, make sure:

1. the key for your widget is correct.
2. if you use customised chat widget you will have to set up following explicitly:

   - contactFlowId
   - instanceId
   - apiGateway
   - region

Comment: I checked them, they look good. I am using the default "Basic Queue". I am following the steps of this page: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/adminguide/tutorial1-test-2.html. The tutorial is very straight forward with only a few steps. In my previous AWS account, this works well. It seems like something wrong in AWS internal?